# Renaming the file by truncating substring

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a file with timestamp include as below

```
File_subj_class_yyyymmddhhmmmiss.txt
```

I need to rename it to below

```
File_subj_class_yyyymmdd.txt
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If all your files are going to be this format every time you could easily write a batch script to loop over the files in the directory and run an `mv` or `move` command and just take the first eight characters after the last underscore.  The loop would look kind of like this but instead of `echo` you'd move the files `for /r %i in (*) do echo %i`

Comment: `mv File_subj_class_yyyymmddhhmmmiss.txt File_subj_class_yyyymmdd.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
f=File_subj_class_yyyymmddhhmmmiss.txt
# or first test with echo "newfile=${f/????????.txt/.txt}"
mv ${f} ${f/????????.txt/.txt}
```